# How to manipulate each item in a latex list in Manim

Tags: python, latex, manim

I'm trying to manipulate each item in a latex list (e.g. change colour, set movement animation) in Manim but it won't let me do so. I can break a latex formula into parts but why can't I do the same to latex list?

This is my code:

```
class TitleAndListOfContent(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        list_of_content = TextMobject(
            '\\begin {itemize}',
            '\\item a',
            '\\item b',
            '\\item c',
            '\\end {itemize}',
        )
        self.play(Write(list_of_content))
        self.wait()
```

and the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../manim/manimlib/extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File ".../manim/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "my_scene.py", line 33, in construct
    '\\end {itemize}',
  File ".../manim/manimlib/mobject/svg/tex_mobject.py", line 148, in __init__
    self, self.arg_separator.join(tex_strings), **kwargs
  File ".../manim/manimlib/mobject/svg/tex_mobject.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.template_tex_file_body
  File ".../manim/manimlib/utils/tex_file_writing.py", line 21, in tex_to_svg_file
    dvi_file = tex_to_dvi(tex_file)
  File ".../manim/manimlib/utils/tex_file_writing.py", line 72, in tex_to_dvi
    "See log output above or the log file: %s" % log_file)
Exception: Xelatex error converting to xdv. See log output above or the log file: media/Tex/a64dc4dc7f5621bd.log
```

For a reference, the visual effect I'm trying to achieve is something like this:
https://youtu.be/BOMNd-bRQ4A?t=31

Answer (score 1):

I opened a issue on the GitHub repo and found a much more promising solution using `BulletedList` class. I think if using Sony's solution `$\\bullet$`, all the items will be centered (or needed to be re-positioned manually) and we want the items to align to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to manim and I couldn't get it to work when I tried (so I don't know why). However, there is a workaround that you can use.

In math mode, you can use a command `$\\bullet$` which creates the dot at the front. So, adapting your program:

```
        list_of_content = TextMobject(
        '$\\bullet$ a \\\\',
        '$\\bullet$ b \\\\',
        '$\\bullet$ c \\\\'
        )
```

Remember the linebreaks so everything isn't on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you all still need this but add

```
r'\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{matrix}'
```

the r says interpret this as a raw sting, so you will not have to add escape characters.